# How to install ArangoDB Docker on an Arch Linux headless server?

Tags: docker, installation, arangodb

I would like to install ArangoDB for Docker on an Arch Linux machine I access via ssh. The ArangoDB Docker download is found here:

[Docker - ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com/download-major/docker/)

This ArangoDb will not be part of a cluster, and there is no active failover. The ArangoDB configuration and the database will need to be persistent.

I will need to access it using the arango command line tools (arangosh, arangoimp, etc.) via ssh. And we'll need http access to the Arango WebUI from the local area network on port 8529 (ArangoDB's default).

I have done these steps:

```
sudo pacman -Syu docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo docker info
```

Docker is installed correctly.

```
Containers: 0
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.09.0-ce
Storage Driver: btrfs
Build Version: Btrfs v4.19 
Library Version: 102
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
seccomp
Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.19.11-arch1-1-ARCH
Operating System: Arch Linux
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 12
Total Memory: 62.82GiB
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

I installed the hello-world docker container:

```
sudo docker run -i -t hello-world
```

> Hello from Docker!
>   This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

Next I ran this command:

```
docker run -e ARANGO_NO_AUTH -d --name arangodb-instance arangodb
```

That produced the expected identifier. However, it does not appear that any containers are running.

```
sudo docker info
Containers: 4
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 4
Images: 2
```

ArangoDB is not accessible at http://localhost:8529

Answer (score 3, accepted):

running

```
docker run -e ARANGO_NO_AUTH -d --name arangodb-instance arangodb
```

will produce identifier, but arangod will exit with error, run

```
docker ps -a
```

there you'll see your container with STATUS

```
Exited (1) 5 seconds ago
```

run

```
docker logs arangodb-instance
```

and you'll see why it exited

```
automatically choosing storage engine
error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
You need to specify one of ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD, ARANGO_NO_AUTH and ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

---

so

to start arango with no password, you need to state

```
-e ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1
```

*you forgot `=1`, `-e` are `KEY=VALUE`*

to access arango remotely, you need to expose port

```
-p 8529:8529
```

to persist data, you need to map them to your host path or volume (volume is best practice)

```
-v arangodb3:/var/lib/arangodb3
```

---

so

for persisting in volume, run

```
docker volume create arangodb3
```

and then

```
docker run -d \
-e ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1 \
-p 8529:8529 \
-v arangodb3:/var/lib/arangodb3 \
--name arangodb-instance \
arangodb/arangodb:3.4.0
```

before you'll run those, you'll need to remove existing container with same name

```
docker stop arangodb-instance
docker rm arangodb-instance
```

to run arangosh, etc run

```
docker exec -it arangodb-instance arangosh
```

---

**notice, that `arangodb/arangodb:3.4.0` instead of `arangodb/arangodb` when executing `docker run`, it's best practice, avoid to run containers without specified version, it will pull `arangodb/arangodb:latest` which can cause, that your staging or prod can pull newer version than you have on dev, which could be a problem if newer version is minor or major**

**also never run arangodb with `ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1` in production or on publicly accesible server**

more details related to Docker are at https://hub.docker.com/_/arangodb/